# FIx gaps in Mysql counter

Tags: mysql

I'd like to find the first "gap" in a counter column in an MySQL table. For example, if there are values 1,2,4 and 5 I'd like to find 3, update 4 to 3, 5 to 4 and so on. The problem is that the gap can be in any point of the table (the first value as well) and it can span multiple values.

I know that it's not a good pattern to have and the standard solution would be to ignore the gaps, but in this case it's not really possible to do so.

Can be done in either SQL (using MySQL) or PHP.

Comment: best you can do is to add a new autoincrement column (that will be without gaps) and then you can keep/drop the old one

Comment: Are you trying to fix/fill  gaps in an AUTOINCREMENT column? Is so... DONT

Comment: In most of cases this operation is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough not a really good way to do things, if your only concern is that you want all of your existing rows numbered without gaps, you could go ahead and renumber them in an update like this.

```
SET @ROW:= 0;
UPDATE TABLE SET COUNTER_ROW = @Row := @Row+1
```